# Of a list of objects select the highest minor. Patch for each major version

Tags: powershell

Seems my brain won't function tonight. [I have a list of objects that are returned from a rest API](https://gist.github.com/jessehouwing/1ceecd510f004c7b24ec68b280ab3f8f). Each object has a version property:

```
id                             8e038650-f7bf-11e8-8a6c-8fff434b4eff
name                           DockerInstaller
version                        {[major, 0], [minor, 209], [patch, 0], [isTest, False]}        
...
```

What I want to achieve is to filter this list grouped by `name`, and then have only 1 version per major version, the one with the highest `minor.patch`.

So, if the service returns:

```
id: some-guid
name: vsbuild
version: {[major, 0], [minor, 209], [patch, 0]} 

id: some-guid
name: vsbuild
version: {[major, 0], [minor, 200], [patch, 0]} 

id: some-guid
name: vsbuild
version: {[major, 1], [minor, 214], [patch, 0]} 

id: some-guid
name: vsbuild
version: {[major, 1], [minor, 200], [patch, 0]} 

...
```

I want to return:

```
id: some-guid
name: vsbuild
versions: @( {[major, 0], [minor, 209], [patch, 0]}, {[major, 1], [minor, 214], [patch, 0]}

...

id: some-other-guid
name: vstest
versions: @( {[major, 0], [minor, 209], [patch, 0]}, {[major, 1], [minor, 214], [patch, 0]}
```

Based on the answers below, in combination with my earlier ugly code I came up with this, which I can still parse with mu sleepy brain. It is easier to understand for me than the Group-Object madness.

```
# find all tasks with the given name
$tasks =  $taskMetadata | Where-Object { $_.name -eq $taskName }

# find all major versions for that task
$majorversions = $tasks | foreach-object { $_.version.major } | Select-Object -Unique

# find the latest version for each major version
$result = $majorversions | ForEach-Object {
    $majorversion = $_

    $tasks | 
        where-object { $_.version.major -eq $majorversion} | 
        sort-object { [version]"$($_.version.major).$($_.version.minor).$($_.version.patch)" } | 
        select-object -last 1
}

return $result
```

There must be a simpler way to express this. But I'm just too tired to figure it out.

The fact that I can't easily group by `$_.version.major` isn't helping.

Is there a bit of PowerShell fairy dust syntax I'm missing?

Code to load the JSON:

```
$org = "jessehouwing-brazil"
$pat = $env:AZURE_DEVOPS_PAT

$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$org"
$header = @{authorization = "Basic $([Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(".:$pat")))"}

$tasks = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$url/_apis/distributedtask/tasks?allversions=true" -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header | ConvertFrom-Json
$taskMetadata = $tasks.value
```

Comment: that's some json... I assume you had to use `ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable` right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, inline comments should explain the thought process:

```
$uri = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jessehouwing/1ceecd510f004c7b24ec68b280ab3f8f/raw/1aeab5a06d409dbff4b6791bafa0357e560284c0/data.json'
# group the objects by name first and enumerate
Invoke-RestMethod $uri | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable | Group-Object name | ForEach-Object {
    # if name is empty, skip this object
    if(-not $_.Name) {
        return
    }

    # group the objects by major and enumerate them
    foreach($group in $_.Group | Group-Object { $_['version']['major'] }) {
        # sort groups by version
        $group.Group | Sort-Object { [version]::new.Invoke(@($_['version']['major', 'minor', 'patch'])) } |
            # pick the highest version in this major group
            Select-Object -Last 1
    }
} | Select-Object id, name, version
```

Comment: I updated my code in the Q. it takes a bit from the answers so far. To me it slightly easier to read than this, though I must admit I've stolen a few things ;). Given that the number of versions is never much more than 10, I can live with the slight perf hit my code is likely causing over the group-construct.

Comment: @jessehouwing If you feel it's more readable then it's perfectly fine. its not really efficient but if it works it works

Comment: @jessehouwing if you want to filter by a specific task name like you have it, using my code you can use `if($_.Name -ne $taskName) { return } ` instead of `if(-not $_.Name) { return }`

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm ... I actually already gave up when you wrote you have a solution. I've got errors trying to import your JSON data. It kind of worked this way:

```
$InputData = 
    Get-Content -Path D:\sample\data.json |
        ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable

$InputData | 
    Select-Object -Property Name, ID, 
        @{
            Name = 'Version'
            Expression = {[version]"$($_.version.major).$($_.version.minor).$($_.version.patch)"}
        },
        @{
            Name = 'Major'
            Expression = {"$($_.version.major)"}
        } |
    Group-Object -Property Name |
        ForEach-Object {
            $_.Group | 
                Group-Object -Property Major |
                ForEach-Object {
                    $_.Group | 
                    Sort-Object -Property Version | 
                        Select-Object -Last 1 -Property Name, ID, Version
                }
        }
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick too. but boy it's hard to read. Not your fault, but this remains one of the toughest parts of PowerShell for me. Transforming, filtering, sorting structured data in a simple expressive syntax.

Comment: You may change the formatting to make it easier to read for you.

Comment: It's not the formatting. I just wish there was a more SQL like group-by construct in which I could add a list of expressions and it would spit out the stuff I want, But I end up with a bunch of hashtables or expression blobs.